# Can anyone help me with what does this part of python code mean?

Tags: python

I would like to know what this small portion of code means, because it seems like in the file that the script creates it adds a line in the end and i believe it might be one of those symbols

```
opened_file.write("%s\n" %user_input)
```

Comment: I do want it to add a new line before it writes but i dont want it to write an empty line in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It writes a line. The content of `user_input` replaces the `%s` (see string interpolation in the docs) and `\n` is the newline character - *after* `user_input`.

Here is a good description of the different "inserting data into strings" methods, including % interpolation (which is now considered outdated):

https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/